# tojson does not work with more than one element when I send an array using python and jinja

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, list

I am trying to send a python list over to my javascript code. My python code looks as follows:

```
return render_template("game.html", images = ['hi','hello'])
```

Note: the ['hi','hello'] list is just a list I am using to explain my problem, my actual list is a bit more complicated and 2-dimensional.

I send the list over via the following code in html.

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}" board = {{images|tojson}}></script>
```

When I display the images list in html below, with the code

```
{{images|tojson}}
```

I see the list I am intending to send over.

In my javascript code, I use

```
var board = document.currentScript.getAttribute('board');
```

to acquire the list. However when I

```
console.log(board)
```

I obtain

["hi",

, and I cant access other parts of board.

Instead if I set images to just ['hi'] and I use console.log(board), I obtain what I intend, namely

["hi"]

.

How do I send lists with more than one entry and multidimensional lists over to my javascript file?